# On MouseOver of one item, need to change color of other items

Tags: wpf, triggers

Want two scenarios as below: 
1. Default color as Green for all items
2. On mouse over, that one item only should be Green and all other items should turn to Yellow at same time.

```
<ListView Name="ListViewDisplay" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" Background="Green" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

With this code all items are always in yellow color.

Comment: Does this attempt not work?

Comment: No. With this code, default color is yellow. I need it as default Green and on mouse over it should change to yellow.

Comment: By default, the IsMouseOver will be False, and as a result, you will always have Yellow as the starting color. Put Green in the IsMouseOver False condition to have it as the default.

Comment: By default, trigger in wpf gets evaluated individually for each item. Is it a possibility that, I could get trigger evaluation for other element's property?